# How to resize to the img tag appropriate?

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I want to show an image in small windows but i need to save on the ratio of the image(I still want that people can know what it is).
For example lets say that the image is 1000X200 pixels, and there's a div that defined as:
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
So I want that the image will wrote like that:

```
<img src="asd.jpg" height=20 width=100 />
```

and not

```
<img src="asd.jpg" height=100 width=100 />
```

or not

```
<img src="asd.jpg"/>
```

and then there's scrolls..

I can work with percentages, but how do I do it.. (and does it even work with percentages alone?)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you set `max-height` and `max-width` in CSS, modern browsers will restrict it to that size but keep the aspect ratio correct:

```
<img src="asd.jpg" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;" />
```

Comment: Can you tell me the supported browsers? that's look exactly like what I need.

Comment: @user719001 should work for anything IE7+.  See http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_dim_max-height.asp If you need IE6 you're in for a world of hurt :\

Answer (score 5):

If your parent `div` has a set `width` and `height`, you could set the max-width and max-height of the `img` to `100%`:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

(It's always a good practice to give images max-width of 100%, for mobile browsers etc.)

Comment: This won't preserve the image's aspect ratio, which is what the question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

If you use javascript, you could simply get the height and width of the image and divide one by the other to get a ratio, then multiply the height and width of the div against that ratio, then set the img dimensions to those numbers.

Obviously that's a very simplistic way to say it, but I'm also not sure if you want to do this with JS or use a strictly CSS solution.

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to avoid js.

Comment: If you're willing to use max-width and max-height that's a better solution anyway.