# how i can make my list work in html?

Tags: html, css

```
 <ul id="ilist">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="" />
                    <p>
                       some text here</p>
                </li>
</ul>
```

the problem is when more item come here sometime icon a little bit bigger make my list buggy. so how i can set the maximum width , height for image (if i set browser resize it). someone can show me how i can set the maximum width , height for image.

**Sollution**

create two ul li in html mockup one in left with image and second with text in right side. that's easier to follow.

Comment: I think, this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748593/how-to-resize-to-the-img-tag-appropriate

Comment: CSS has [`max-width`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width) and [`max-height`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-height) properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul id="ilist">
      <li>
          <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="" **width="500" height="400"**/>
          <p>some text here</p>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Or do it with css:

```
#ilist li img{
max-height: 400px;
max-width: 500px
}
```