# How to get images in same size?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here am doing with responsive rotating [cube](http://www.albanx.com/cubeslider/examples1.php). Now i have changed it like take images from on folder using php. But these images are not in same size. So while rotating cube images are not good.

[`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/qmKzD/) am attaching code with php too.  I think some javascript is doing like this.
Am trying to get same size images, but not getting. Can anyone help to get same size images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize to the img tag appropriate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748593/how-to-resize-to-the-img-tag-appropriate)

Comment: @ejay_francisco thanks for you comment. have used style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;" also . But while rotating cube images height was not good.